# LEN Invalid Identifier SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that shows the names of countries from a table in one column, and lists the number of letters in each name in another column. I read up on the `LEN` function and tried using it, but I get an error that says it's an invalid identifier. Am I using it correctly or is there a more suitable SQL command I should be using?

```
SELECT 
    COUNTRY_NAME, LEN(COUNTRY_NAME)
FROM 
    COUNTRIES;
```

Comment: Maybe is LENGHT?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different databases have different names for functions.  Although `len()` is frequently used, `length()` is also commonly used.  You can try:

```
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME, LENGTH(COUNTRY_NAME)
FROM COUNTRIES;
```

You are clearly learning about databases.  You should figure out what database you are using and how to use the documentation for it.